# I want to extract the value of a variable from different file in velocity template

Tags: velocity

I have a "header.vm", in which I have a variable named "tableHeight" and I want to use the value of this "tableHeight" variable in different .vm file.
I am able to extract the value in "header.vm" using below codes:

```
#set ($resultGroup = $resultFields.getChild("field-group"))
#set ($tableHeight = $resultGroup.getAttribute("tableHeight").getValue())
```

and in another file I am using:
`#parse(header.vm)` 
and trying to use "tableHeight" but its not having the value

Answer (score 0):

You should use #include instead of #parse directive in your case, because you want to parse the tableHeight inside your file. See [include vs parse](http://people.apache.org/%7Ehenning/velocity/html/ch05s05.html):

> The #include directive allows the template designer to import a local file. Its contents replace the #include directive in the template. These contents are inserted as-is, they are not rendered through the template engine.
>
> The #parse directive works similar to #include, but the contents of the file will be part of the template rendering process and all VTL elements in the file will be evaluted.